# SQL Select Column name where true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with about 50 tinyint columns (acting as Booleans). These are options that are either true (1) or false (0).

I need to be able to select only the columns that are true (value = 1), and I need to get the names of those columns. I have no idea how to write that.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems like a strange thing to require in SQL and something that belong in presentation/a logic layer, but I guess you could always just build the SQL string dynamically and/or use temporary tables to calculate such things before a final select.

Comment: what rdbms are you working with?

Comment: Is your table supposed to hold only one row? If that's the case then it smells like bad design especially when all the columns are the same type. The correct approach is to use a table with two columns `Name` (varchar) and `Value` (bit/int)

Comment: Tag dbms used. (ANSI SQL has a boolean data type, but no tinyint.)

Comment: I'm trying to grab all the values that are true so they can be listed in PHP. I could do this in PHP, but this is more flexible for if columns are added later (this is a possibility).

I don't know what dbms I'm working with. I'm using phpmyadmin though. I know when I was setting it up, I specified Boolean, but it change it to tinyint. The table say InnoDB if that's it?

My table is actually currently holding 78 rows, and needs to be able to be added to. Each Column is for an option that is true in at least 1 of the rows

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an `UNPIVOT` solution. `UNPIVOT` is supported in [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) and [SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), but I suspect you're not using those databases. Hence, hard-code it manually:

```
SELECT id, 'col1' AS col
WHERE col1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'col2' AS col
WHERE col2 = 1
...
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'col50' AS col
WHERE col50 = 1
```

I put a hypothetical `id` column there, in case your table contains several rows. In case it contains only one row, that `id` column might not be needed.

Comment: So, I wrote up one part of that statement you suggested, but it just returned the value (1) instead of the column name. My code looks something like this:
`SELECT 'col1' AS col FROM 'table_name' WHERE 'col1' = 1 AND 'item_id'= 1001` - Advice?

Comment: The query I suggested will not return (1) instead of the column name, neither does the one you posted in your comment. But of course, I don't know what you *really* executed when you say that your code looks *something* like this. Also, *how* did you execute the query? I.e. with PHP? Java? Some DB tool?

Comment: The code is exactly that, except with different column and table names. I executed it with phpmyadmin and PHP, both returned the value as 1.

Comment: @Dezonus: The query itself doesn't return 1. It may well be that the value `col1` is coerced into an int somewhere. I cannot tell from the information I have why that happens...

Comment: Well, the datatype is a tinyint, so could it be that phpmyadmin and PHP are interpreting it as an int? And if so, is there something else that I need to perhaps add/change to handle that?

Comment: But this query is not selecting any tinyints. It's selecting a string column. Nothing in the query itself is coercing the type to tinyint...

Comment: The problem seems to be with the "AS col". The SQL is not registering that as anything. I changed it to "AS bla", and got exactly the same result. I can't find what I would need to put there.